# Looking for a better way of using material3 Text Field's onStartIconClickListener and onEndIconClickListener on RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

[google keep label ui for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJibs.png) I'm trying to recreate the way google keep's process and design for label interface where the if the label item is in focus, the start and end icon changes and now has onclickListeners

While searching for solutions I've found that this type of way to implement an OnItemClick where you use an interface that has on itemclick function that will be passed to the fragment

```
interface RecyclerViewEvent {

    
    fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    
}
```

then I've added it as a parameter for the adapter and add View.OnClickLister on viewholder where it has an onClickfunction where you can put the your onItemClick function from the interface which will be triggered on the fragment by extending the interface to your fragment

```
class LabelListAdapter(
    private val label: List<Label>,
    private val listener: RecyclerViewEvent
): RecyclerView.Adapter<LabelListAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    inner class ViewHolder(
        view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener{


        var labelOutline: TextInputLayout

        init {

            //labelEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.label_edittext)
            labelOutline = view.findViewById(R.id.label_row_outlinedTextField)
            labelOutline.setOnClickListener(this)

        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {

            val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
            if (position !=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position)
            }
            Log.i("Testing", "adapter label position: $position")
        }

    }
```

this doesn't go well with my task since the viewOnclick function doesn't trigger when pressing the textfield. It only triggers when when you click the top and bottom edge of the textfield

so I've changed functions on the RecyclerViewEvent interface

```
interface RecyclerViewEvent {

    fun onStartIconClick(position: Int)
    fun onEndIconClick(position: Int)
}
```

then I use this in OnBindViewHolder class to trigger the OnStartIconClickfunction

```
viewHolder.labelOutline.setStartIconOnClickListener {
                    if (viewHolder.labelOutline.isFocused||viewHolder.labelOutline.editText!!.isFocused){
                        Log.i("testing", "viewholder " +
                                "postition $position" +
                                "end icon pressed")
                        onStartIconClick(position)

                    }
                    
                }
```

then On my fragment I will use the function to delete an Item

```
  override fun onStartIconClick(position: Int) {
        val item = labels[position]
        //some code to delete an Item
    }
```

Am I doing it right or is there a more efficient way
I hope I could help you with my solution
I'm just making a portfolio so I could find a job soon